# Using a Dash dropdown and call back to update a global variable

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

So the jist is i have a variable that is used to select if i want to display a 2d scatter plot or a 3d scatter plot.

the logic is essentially this

```
dim = 2

if dim == 2
    2D html and elements
if dim == 3
    3D html and elements

2d graph callback

3d graph callback
```

but i want to make it so that i could have a dropdown and i can choose between 2 and 3 updating the `dim` variable that is globally defined.

An example of this is below

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output


app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(['2D', '3D'], '2D', id='demo-dropdown'),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_output(value):
    if value == '2D':
        dim = 2
    else:
         dim = 3

    return f'You have selected {value}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

In this case i want the `dim` variable to be updated to 2 or 3 each time i chose a dropdown item.

Please do let me know if this is possible or if there is an alternative implementation.

When i try it in my code ( not the same as above ) it doesnt crash but it doesnt change `dim`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of issues at play here.

Firstly, your code as written does not declare `dim` as a global variable. The variable is assigned within your `update_output()` function, which makes it local and means it will be destroyed as soon as the function exits. You may be interested in an [intro on global and local variables at w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp).

However, the next issue is that Dash explicitly [recommends against using global variables](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks#why-global-variables-will-break-your-app).

The right way to manage global state is using the [dcc.Store()](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) component in Dash, for which there is a [tutorial here](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks#example-1---storing-data-in-the-browser-with-dcc.store).

Taking your above example, you would use a `dcc.Store` as follows:

```
app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(['2D', '3D'], '2D', id='demo-dropdown'),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
    dcc.Store(id='dim')
])
    
@app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    Output('dim', 'data'),
    Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_output(value):
    if value == '2D':
        dim = 2
    else:
         dim = 3

    return f'You have selected {value}', dim
```

You can then read the `dim` Store in other callbacks as follows:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('some_output', 'children'),
    Input('dim', 'data')
)
def some_callback(dim_data):
    if dim_data == '1':
        pass
    return "blah"
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your detailed answer, i will attempt this and update accordingly !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mutable object like a dictionary to store the information about dim so that it can be changed from within `update_function`. For example:

```
dim_dict = {'dim': None}
```

And then inside the callback:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_output(value):
    if value == '2D':
        dim_dict['dim'] = 2
    else:
        dim_dict['dim'] = 3

    return f'You have selected {value}'
```